# Protected Configuration: useMachineContainer's default value?

Tags: asp.net, xml, default-value

In ASP.NET, when I'm using Protected Configuration, I'll specify something similar to [the following](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68ze1hb2.aspx) in my web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <configProtectedData defaultProvider="SampleProvider">
    <providers>
      <add name="SampleProvider" 
        type="System.Configuration.RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider, 
              System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
              PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a,
             processorArchitecture=MSIL"
        keyContainerName="SampleKeys" 
        useMachineContainer="true" />
    </providers>
  </configProtectedData>
</configuration>
```

If I don't include it, what is the default value of the "useMachineContainer" attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the [Reference Source implementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Configuration/System/Configuration/RSAProtectedConfigurationProvider.cs,28a2fa258dadf357) for [RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Configuration.RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider.aspx), and DpapiProtectedConfigurationProvider the UseMachineContainer is initialised to a default value of 'true' (if no value is set in configuration)